# Heroku uninitialized constant Rails:Initializer (NameError) (noWWW Rack Middleware)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redirect, url-rewriting, heroku

I'm running Cedar stack on Heroku, rails 3.1.3.

using:
http://trevorturk.com/2009/11/05/no-www-rack-middleware/

When I push to Heroku, I get:

```
app[web.1]: => Rails 3.1.3 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:15548
app[web.1]: => Call with -d to detach
app[web.1]: => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
app[web.1]: Exiting
app[web.1]: /app/config/environment.rb:7:in `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant Rails::Initializer (NameError)
```

Anyone have any ideas whats going on?

Here's my environment.rb (AppName = proper name for my app. i.e. thats not the issue)

```
# Load the rails application
require File.expand_path('../application', __FILE__)

# Initialize the rails application
AppName::Application.initialize!

Rails::Initializer.run do |config|
  config.middleware.use "NoWWW" if RAILS_ENV == 'production'
end
```

lib/no_www.rb:

```
class NoWWW

  STARTS_WITH_WWW = /^www\./i

  def initialize(app)
    @app = app
  end

  def call(env)
    if env['HTTP_HOST'] =~ STARTS_WITH_WWW
      [301, { 'Location' => Rack::Request.new(env).url.sub(/www\./i, '') }, ['Redirecting...']]
    else
      @app.call(env)
    end
  end

end
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem using Rails 3.1. I ended up using this [post](http://bluediapente.com/posts/2012/02/10/how-to-do-www-to-non-www-301-redirect-on-your-heroku-rails-app). It appears to be more involved than other solutions but there are really only two steps.

Make sure to change `yoursite.com` in the code. I overlooked this and had to rush another deployment after the fix.

Answer (score 0):

The error you're receiving is telling you that you're referencing an old version of Rails. Rails 3.1 initializes quite a bit differently than it did 2 years ago when that article was written. In particular, the problem is with the now deprecated `Rails::Initializer` in this block:

```
Rails::Initializer.run do |config|
  config.middleware.use "NoWWW" if RAILS_ENV == 'production'
end
```

You might have more luck with [rack-rewrite](https://github.com/jtrupiano/rack-rewrite). Regardless, check out the official Rails documentation for a good breakdown of current [configuration](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html) and [initialization](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/initialization.html).

Comment: Any idea how to implement rack-rewrite for what I want? The README on github doesn't really explain too well...

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your middleware file is not being loaded.  Place your middleware class, no_www.rb in app/middleware.  This way it will be auto-loaded by Rails.  Then add your config statement to application.rb, near the end.

```
    ...

    # Configure Rack middleware
    config.middleware.use 'NoWWW'

  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue; I know it's a late answer but I wanted to add this for whoever needed it.

Make sure that your OmniauthCallbacksController IS IN A `users` FOLDER. `"app/controllers/users/omniauth_callbacks_controller.rb"`